# Startactivity(intent) handle invalid url

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

im getting some urls from firebase to download a pdf in a repository of my collage in a fragment , thats work fine, but when the repository its  updated , the urls change , so i get invalid download urls and the app crash
the question is , how to handle this invalid url?

```
String url = http://NotaValidURL.com.info ;
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
try {   
 startActivity(i);

        } catch(LinkageError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Aun no esta disponible desde bedelia",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

im not realy sure witch error should i catch  ty !

log

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: ar.com.puebloyreforma.pyr, PID: 7587
                  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= }
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1936)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1615)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                      at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:230)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:806)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:920)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:908)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:897)
                      at ar.com.puebloyreforma.pyr.FragmentMesas.onClick(FragmentMesas.java:95)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Could you share the error log

Comment: ill edit the question sorry for not upload after i was in trouble to debugg not on my regular terminal